# Kotlin and Gson Fetch from API a JSON object with any number of Keys and store in Room database

Tags: kotlin, gson, android-room

Suppose I have a service that returns some JSON where I know before hand some keys, but not the others.

I want to store the data in my room database such that the known properties on the JSON are properties on my entity, but the entire payload of unknown keys is also stored.

I can do it like so:

Model

```
@Entity
data class Whatever(
@PrimaryKey
val id: String,
val somethingElse: JsonObject?)
```

Usage

```
val gson = GsonBuilder()
                .disableHtmlEscaping()
                .create()
    

val json = "{\"id\":\"42\",\"extra\":[{\"z\":\"banana\"}]}"
val raw = gson.fromJson(this, JsonObject::class.java)
val model = gson.fromJson(this, Whatever::class.java)
model.somethingElse = raw
// save to database here
```

This works but it seems plenty inefficient to me (I need to do this to hundreds of thousands of records).

Is there a way to streamline it such that I only have to make one `gson.fromJson()` call?

Or, better yet, is there some other and better way to store my arbitrary data in Room.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you could simplify `object : TypeToken<JsonObject>() { }.type` to `JsonObject::class.java` (same for `TypeToken<Whatever>`). `TypeToken` is only needed when you use generic types, such as `List<Whatever>`.

Comment: @Marcono1234 obviously in my code I use generics, and have extension methods for everything so I had to extract it back to the bare minimum so that it is clear in stack. Thanks for trying to help though.

Comment: Maybe you could make it more efficient by not parsing `model` from the original JSON again, but instead from `raw` (to avoid parsing the JSON twice): `model = gson.fromJson(raw, Whatever::class.java)`. And in case your `Whatever` class only has very few known properties, you could even manually extract them from `raw` and construct the `Whatever` instance yourself, avoiding the second `fromJson` call completely.